# Error when entering decimal number in clojure repl

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

When I enter `user> (* 10 .5)` in my clojure repl I get this message:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: .5 in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)
```

I know I can do this `(/ 10 2)` or `(* 10 (/ 1 2))`.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

I'm using clojure 1.5, emacs and nrepl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the [clojure reader](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Reader%20forms) uses the form [NNNN.NNNN](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Numbers) for doubles. .5 should be written as

```
(* 10 0.5)
```

And as a side note it reads this as a double, if you want a float you have to cast it.

It is perfectly fine to start a var's name with `.`

```
user> (def .im-a-normal-var 42)
#'user/.im-a-normal-var
user> .im-a-normal-var
42
```